# Three.js How to slerp quaternion to Pathline?

Tags: three.js

image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTrtg.png)

My purpose is to make these cubes rotate along the red line on the left, and the angle of each square is evenly interpolated.
These are some squares I created while using Quaternion.slerp. Obviously they are incorrect. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I figured it out myself.
The solution is not an algorithm but an some Angle and some transformations.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWduq.png)